# Redundant parts of code

Tags: php, optimization, redundancy

I'm writing a small .php code, the idea is similar to this:

We have 2 Persons, Person A and Person B, and 8 fields of data, 4 for each person (order, name, role, pic). The example of data:

Person A:

- order: 1
- name: Alex
- role: Customer
- pic: alex.jpg

Person B:

- order: 2
- name: Felix
- role: Supplier
- pic: felix.jpg

The idea of order field is to determine which person should be displayed first on the page. According to the example, Person A should be displayed first, but the order may be different. Person B may have 0 order, and then Person B should be first.

I've achieved the result, by writing this code:

```
$first_person_order = // here I get order for Person A;
$second_person_order = // here I get order for Person B;

$first_person_name;
$first_person_role;
$first_person_pic;

$second_person_name;
$second_person_role;
$second_person_pic;

if ($first_person_order < $second_person_order) {
    $first_person_name = // here I get name for Person A;
    $first_person_role = // here I get role for Person A;
    $first_person_pic = // here I get pic for Person A;
    $second_person_name = // here I get name for Person B;
    $second_person_role = // here I get role for Person B;
    $second_person_pic = // here I get pic for Person B;
} else {
    $first_person_name =  // here I get name for Person B;
    $first_person_role = // here I get role for Person B;
    $first_person_pic = // here I get pic for Person B;
    $second_person_name = // here I get name for Person A;
    $second_person_role = // here I get role for Person A;
    $second_person_pic = // here I get pic for Person A;
}
```

But I've a feeling this is not a good solution, it looks very redundant, but I really have no idea how to make it better due to my poor PHP knowledge! I would be extremely happy to get any sort of help / solutions. Thank you!

Comment: can you show the code where you are displaying persons on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays where the index is the order number.

```
$pers = [];
$pers[$first_person_order] = array($first_person_name,$first_person_role,$first_person_pic);
$pers[$second_person_order] = array($second_person_name,$second_person_role,$second_person_pic);
```

When you need to echo them, traverse the array. They will be in order.

```
$arrlength = count($pers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $pers[$x][1];
}
```

Comment: yes it will give error, but I thought you want to display according to the order so I assumed that order won't be null. If it can be null then please specify how you would want to display it.